# Rails getting the current time without the date

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, date, time

I know there are a lot of questions regarding date and time for Rails, but I can't seem to solve the problem I have.

I'm probably just being stupid about this.. anyway, my problem is that I want to get the current time *without* the date attached.

For example, when I use the following I get:

```
Time.now => 2012-06-29 09:23:04 -0400
```

or

```
Time.current => Fri, 29 Jun 2012 09:23:23 EDT -04:00
```

I would like to obtain the current time without having the date. i.e. just

```
09:23:04 -0400
```

or

```
09:23:23 EDT -04:00
```

If there are questions out there that already addresses this, I'd appreciate being pointed to them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to get the bits of the time that you want, in the format you want them.

```
puts Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %z") # "09:33:00 -0400"

puts Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %Z %z") # "09:33:00 EDT -0400"
```

Comment: [`to_formatted_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) seems like a better option.

Answer (score 3):

```
Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") # "18:33:00"
```

*Don't use `%I` without `%p` (won't know am/pm)*